# In PHP, how can I compare three queries to select corresponding rows?

Tags: php, sql

I have three individual queries that are used to select users dependent on the variables. Each user has a unique user ID which is on each table effected by the queries. Is there a way, with PHP, that I can only select the users that return for all three queries?

Comment: Show us these queries. There's probably a way to combine all three into one query that gives you the desired result. Otherwise, give us more details and code samples. Otherwise we can pretty much only say *Yes, there's a way.*

Comment: The best answer depends a lot on the nature of the queries. You probably need to provide more specifics to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: The queries are dynamic and are usually quite long so I can't really show you a definite one, but for example: 
QUERY 1:SELECT * FROM user_data_1 WHERE `dob` = '2001-01-01'
QUERY 2:SELECT * FROM user_data_2 WHERE `gender` = 'male'
QUERY 3:SELECT * FROM user_data_3 WHERE ( `network` = 'T-Mobile')

Comment: In a properly structured database you should be able to make one query along the lines of `SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN user_data ON users.id = user_data.user_id WHERE user_data.network = 'T-Mobile' AND user_data.dob = ... AND ...`. That depends on your database structure though, without which we can hardly give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, do an inner join on all three tables using the common field.

Ex:

```
 Select cola, colb
 From tablea join tableb
 On a.commoncolumn=b.commoncolumn
 Join tablec on a.commoncolumn=c.commoncolumn
 Where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3 queries have to be run independently, you could use a union query to get the three invididual results sets lumped into a single set, then do an outer query to check which userIDs have 3 different sources:

```
select count(SOURCE) as cnt, userID
from (
    select 'tableA' as SOURCE, userID
    from tableA
    where ...

    union all

    select 'tableB' as SOURCE, userID
    from tableB
    where ...

    union all

    select 'tableC' as SOURCE, userID
    from tableC
    where ...
) as subquery
group by userID
having cnt = 3
```